# Change an attribute ina different webpage

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frameset

So I have one webpage, sectioned off into two different webpages, one on the left, and another on the right by use of frameset. The left has radio buttons, and the right has an iframe

Both webpages ref a javascript file

When triggered, the radio buttons go to a function in my referenced javascript file

```
function foo(){
    //document.getElementById("id").src="www.foo.com";
}
```

In this function I want to change the src of the iframe of the webpage on the right, but from what I understand the uri generated from the radio button is from the page where the button is. Is there a way the javascript function cane can change the attribute in an html file even though it was not called from that file

Comment: If you downvote my question, can you atleast comment why I got a downvote? Was I not clear?

Comment: Read up on cross-frame JavaScript communication. Any frame can talk to any other frame provided they are of the same domain. For a child to talk to the parent page, for example, the prefix `parent`. is used.

Comment: Thanks it looks promising. If it works please feel free to post than an answer so I can give you your deserves points.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to change your approach.

Try changing your sections for simple `div`s and looking at the [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Hope that helps.